# curl "| sh" command

Tags: curl, meteor, sh

What does "| sh" mean in this particular line. I'm trying to google it for better understanding, but it seems I can't find the right term for it.

```
$ curl https://install.meteor.com | sh
```

I was able to run it and it downloaded meteorjs however, I was really curious with "| sh".

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`|` can be read as "pipe"

The above command means "pipe the result of curl to sh" - a.k.a "get the script from this url and run it using sh"

Comment: nice one! thanks @charlieg for explaining it in layman's term. :)

Comment: Be careful when you use this pattern to install software. It's risky. The good news is that the script is being downloaded over HTTPS instead of HTTP (`https://` vs `http://`), but it can still be problematic. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/12/12/security-spectrum-curl-sh/?utm_source=stackoverflow-ao&utm_campaign=security-spectrum-curl-sh&utm_medium=referral